# Flutter, Dart, FireBase: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) - onTap GestureDetcture

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error when I run my app.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s)

> Exception caught by gesture   Invalid argument(s)

[image: Error]

**Code**

```
onTap: () async {
                                  var userDetail = await FirebaseFirestore
                                      .instance
                                      .collection("Users")
                                      .doc(
                                          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                      .get();
                                  final pID =
                                      userDetail.data()['ID'];

                                  final pName = userDetail.data()['Name'];
                                  var dName = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      .data()['Doc Name'];
                                  var dID = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                      .data()['DocID'];
                                  var dcoumentID=
                                      pID + pName + dName + dID;
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                      return Screen1(
                                          doctor:
                                              snapshot.data.docs[index].data(),
                                          doctumentID:
                                              dcoumentID);
                                    }),
                                  );
                                },
```

This code works in the rest of the application only this part is throwing the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error isn't revealing any information.  You're fetching data feom Firestore, make sure that all values e.g. pID, pName etc are non null. Most chance is that there's some null value.

Comment: Yes I was just checking they are not giving null.

Comment: Did you try debugger? If you don't know, just remove all the code in onTap function and add each line one by one and then see, I hope it's the simplest way to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in one of the fields I am trying to access, I did not add space.
Always check if you typed a field's name correctly, and a collection name correctly.
Thank you.

```
onTap: () async {
                                  var userDetail = await FirebaseFirestore
                                      .instance
                                      .collection("Users")
                                      .doc(
                                          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                      .get();
                                  final pID =userDetail.data()['ID'];
    
                                      final pName = userDetail.data()['Name'];
                                      var dName = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                          .data()['Doc Name'];
                                      var dID = snapshot.data.docs[index]
                                          .data()['Doc ID']; //changed field name
                                      var dcoumentID=
                                          pID + pName + dName + dID;
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                          return Screen1(
                                              doctor:
                                                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data(),
                                              doctumentID:
                                                  dcoumentID);
                                        }),
                                      );
                                    },
```